# How do you export a variable through shell script without using source command?

Tags: shell, export

I wanted to export variables based on the condition as:

```
if [[ "$1" == *"eu"* ]]; then
 export API_URL=https://xx-gateway-eu.xx.com/cccccccc
elif [[ "$1" == *"as"* ]]; then
 export API_URL=https://xx-gateway-as.xx.com/cccccccc
else
 export API_URL=https://xx-gateway-na.xx.com/cccccccc
fi
```

When i execute the script using "./script.sh yyy.ee.kkk.eu.dd.com", it got executed successfully but i dont see the variable got exported, echo $API_URL is empty. Could see the variable is set if i use 'source ./script.sh' and i understand the reason why its behaving like this. But, is there a way to achieve it as part of the shell script execution itself and without using source?

Answer (score 1):

Not as far as I know,  because that execution happens in a *new* process. This is what the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) line is all about in a script.

`source` (or `.` if you prefer) is what you want here really.

##### EDIT: or use `eval` if you *really* need to

...If you really want to avoid `source`, you could use `eval` to ensure you stay in-process:

```
$ 1=foo-eu- eval "$(cat script.sh)"
$ echo $API_URL
https://xx-gateway-as.xx.com/cccccccc
```

With the normal [caveats about `eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead).

Comment: Understood, but looking for a way to achieve natively on the script without using source command, as we dont have the luxury to use it.

Comment: Can you use `eval` then?

Comment: Could you please let me know the exact format to use eval here?

Comment: @devops1 sorry missed that - sure, updated